# Convert JSON to an object, then performing different actions based on object type

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Previously, I have an OrderedDictionary where I convert it into JSON, then at some parts of the code I need to deserialize it back to OrderedDictionary.

Now, I need to change the type of that property to a List. I need to do a backward compatibility. How can I code such that when deserializing the JSON, I deserialize it to an object, then I check if object is List, do something, else if object is OrderedDictionary, do something.

Currently if I deserialize it to an object, I get a JObject. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.

What I'm expecting to have is something like:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonString, new object());

if (x is List)
 doSomething1();
else if (x is OrderedDictionary)
 doSomething2();
```

Comment: something like : obj1.GetType() == typeof(int) : doSomething1() ? doSomething2(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below:

```
object x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

if (x is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) // OrderedDictionary
    doSomething1();
else if (x is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray) // List
    doSomething2();
```

This works only with Json.NET and `jsonString` must be string serialized also by Json.NET.

From Json.NET's [Serialization Guide](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm), List (implemented `IList`) would be serialized in JSON array, and `OrderedDictionary` (implemented `IDictionary`) would be serialized as JSON object.
Therefore, the returned value would be of different type, which are of `JArray` and `JObject` respectively.

Comment: So, if it returns a JArray, how can I convert x to a List?

Comment: You may call `JArray.ToObject<T>()` to convert to your list type `T`, `JArray` also supports retrieving array members by index, check http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm for details. If you need an example, provide the format of your list object.

Answer (score 2):

use the type like that:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json,new OrderedDictionary());
System.Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
```

Output: 
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

Comment: No, the issue I'm facing is, I'm not sure the type I have to pass in, I can't just pass in new OrderedDictionary. My json could be an OrderedDictionary or a List, so if it is a List and I want to convert it to an OrderedDict, it will throw and exception..

Answer (score 1):

The JSON library won't (can't) help you decide the best target type, you need to tell it. What do you think is the "correct" target type if you don't provide one?

```
//JSON:   { Name = "sweety", Age = 1 }

class Kid
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set }
}

class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set }
}
```

In another word, a JSON string has no information of the type it comes from. So you need to tell the library to de-serialize the JSON string to a specific type (even an anonymous type).

I think you shouldn't serialize the `OrderedDictionary<K,V>`(or the `List<T>`) itself, but the items inside them, and add one more property indicating the type like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Flag { get; set; }
    public MyData[] DataObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Put the items of your dictionary/list into a `MyClass` instance and serialize it (with different Flag property values). And you will always get an instance of `MyClass` after de-serialization, check the `Flag` property to decide which section of code should be run.

Comment: I agree with this answer; you should stub out your class to match the object returned. If you need any custom parsing convert the object to a JToken and evaluate the type.